# How to fix "Windows Script Host Error" code 800A000D

Tags: vbscript, runtime-error, windows-8.1, error-code

I keep getting the Windows Script Host error whenever I restart my computer. I also get the APC_MISMATCH_INDEX blue screen error whenever I try to play a certain game on my computer. The windows script host error is 800A000D, line 10 char 2, type mismatch "CInt". I'm not sure how to fix this and have included a copy of the code in question below. Are these errors related? If you need more information please let me know.

For the APC_INDEX_MISMATCH I have tried repairing registry items, ran a system file scan, checked for hard drive corruption, and tested for RAM corruption. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the game in question which also did not solve the issue. For the windows script host error, I'm not even sure where to begin.

```
If (fso.FileExists(ccdat)) Then
    Set setting = fso.OpenTextFile(ccdat, 1, 0)
    cc = CInt(setting.ReadLine)
    setting.Close
```

I'm hoping to get the result of not having that error code pop up anymore and stop my computer from blue screening everytime I try to play that one game.

Comment: Add the line `MsgBox .` right before ` = (.)`, and share the MsgBox output.

Comment: You're getting that error because the data read from the file cannot be converted to an integer. That can happen when a) the data is not convertible to an integer (for instance a string like "abc") or b) the file is empty (no data could be read). In case of the latter you'll get an error 0x3e when running `setting.ReadLine` without the `CInt()`.

Comment: And no, the script host error is most certainly not related to any bluescreens. For troubleshooting the latter [start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x1--apc-index-mismatch).